# how to set multiple kotlin variables in one line

Tags: kotlin

I want to fill two variables in the same line, but I don't know the best way to do it at kotlin

```
var a:String? = null
var b:String? = null
a, b = "Text"
```

Comment: Kotlin just doesn't support this syntax. You could do `val (a, b) = "Text" to "Text"`, but you will have to write "Text" twice, and it will create a `Pair`-object and immediately deconstruct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible in Kotlin (unless you are ready to resort to some contrived constructs with repetition as described in other answers and comments). You cannot even write

```
    a = b = "Text"
```

because weirdly enough, assignments are **not** expressions in Kotlin (as opposed to almost everything else like `if`, `return`, `throw`, `swicth`, etc., which *are* expressions in Kotlin, but not in Java, for example).

So, if you want to assign exactly the same value without repetition (of the assigned value), you'll have to write

```
    a = "Text"
    b = a
```

Note, that there is also an `also` function (pun intended), so technically you can write the following if you really want to stay on one line

```
    a = "Text".also { b = it }
```

but I doubt it is really worth it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a: String? = null; var b: String? = null
```

or

```
var (a: String?, b: String?) = null to null
```

But please don't ever do so

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an inline array, iterate through and assign values.

```
listOf(a, b, c, d).forEach { it = "Text" }
```